# Integrating the API of cleartrip.com

Tags: php, api

I have an api key of **cleartrip.com** website. I have do integration with my website, which means i like to use web services provided by **cleartrip.com**. But i in confusion how to do this. Please help me for integration. I have try following code in php, but i don't receive any response.

```
<?php       
$header_array = array('X-CT-API-KEY' => 'here my api key');
$options = array(headers => $header_array);
$r = new HttpRequest('http://api.cleartrip.com/air/1.0/search?from=BOM&to=DEL&depart-date=2008-06-06&return-date=2008-06-06', HttpRequest::METH_GET,$options);
try 
{
    $r->send();
    echo $r->getResponseBody();
    print_r($r);
    if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200)
    {
        echo "Hi";
        echo   $r->getResponseBody();
    }
} 
catch (HttpException $ex) 
{
    echo "sss".$ex;
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to detail the question better. What do you mean "I cannot give any response". Is the server not responding? Are you getting a http error? What exactly is not going correctly?

Comment: `array(headers => $header_array);` is not exactly valid php. `header` is a constant, which you almost certainly haven't defined.

Comment: "Not authorized to access the service" i will get in catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an actual string key? i.e.

```
$options = array('headers' => $header_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this curl call works for you

```
$headers = array('X-CT-API-KEY: INSERT_KEY_HERE');
$url = 'http://api.staging.cleartrip.com/air/1.0/search?from=BOM&to=DEL&depart-date=2008-06-06&return-date=2008-06-06';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Comment: It works proper but it will cannot give reply on proper time. it take so much time. how to reduce time of this.